# Python Ошибка в цикле

Tags: python

```
import pygame


WINDOW_SIZE = width, height = 900, 900   # Размер окна (пиксели) + видимая область
FIELD_SIZE = horizontal, vertical = 10, 5   # Размеры поля (ячейки)
CELL_SIZE = 50   # Размер одной квадратной клетки (пиксели)

lst = [[0, 0, ['properties']]] * (horizontal * vertical)
x_cell = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i][0] = x_cell
    x_cell += CELL_SIZE

print(lst)
```

Это код. Я собираюсь создать список, внутри которого будут списки, внутри которых первый элемент будет увеличеваться на 50.
Вот, что ввыводит:

```
[[2450, 0, ['properties']], [2450, 0, ['properties']], [2450, 0, ['properties']], [2450, 0, ['properties']], ...]
```

Comment: `lst = [[0, 0, ['properties']] for _ in range(horizontal * vertical)]`.

Comment: Зачем писать так `for i in range(len(lst))` и брать в цикле `lst[i]`, если можно сразу итерироваться по элементам списка? `for i in lst` и брать в цикле `i`?

Answer (score 2):

> lst = [[0, 0, ['properties']]] * (horizontal * vertical)

list это изменяемый объект, операции над которым не создают новых объектов, а все переменные в пайтоне - это указатели. поэтому подобный способ создания множества списков приводит к тому что все они указывают на одни и те же данные. и при изменении одного списка меняются все. хотя на самом деле меняются лишь данные, а так как все списки связаны, то мы получаем то что видим.

```
import pygame


WINDOW_SIZE = width, height = 900, 900   # Размер окна (пиксели) + видимая область
FIELD_SIZE = horizontal, vertical = 10, 5   # Размеры поля (ячейки)
CELL_SIZE = 50   # Размер одной квадратной клетки (пиксели)

lst = [[0, 0, ['properties']]] * (horizontal * vertical)
x_cell = 0
lst[i][0] = None

print(lst)
```

вам нужно создавать списки либо копировать их вместо копирования ссылок. например

`lst = [[0, 0, ['properties']] for _ in range(horizontal * vertical)]`

А еще лучше вот так, чтобы не делать итерацию по всему размеру дважды.

```
import pygame


WINDOW_SIZE = width, height = 900, 900   # Размер окна (пиксели) + видимая область
FIELD_SIZE = horizontal, vertical = 10, 5   # Размеры поля (ячейки)
CELL_SIZE = 50   # Размер одной квадратной клетки (пиксели)

lst = []
x_cell = 0
for i in range(horizontal * vertical):
    lst.append([x_cell, 0, ['properties']])
    x_cell += CELL_SIZE

print(lst)
```